# While e if : Mudar as verificação do while e if para varieveis

Tags: linux, shell-script

Estou criando um script para automação de um processo, porém no script tenho que ler uma diretório e inserir o conteúdo (nome de arquivos) em um arquivo de texto e no while ler cada linha para processar os arquivos.
A pergunta é,tem como fazer esse mesmo processo no lugar do arquivo ser uma varievél?

Script:

```
# Declaração de variáveis e arquivos
DIRETORIO="/pasta_alvo"
> $DIRETORIO/arq.txt # limpo os arquivos do processo
> $DIRETORIO/trt.txt

ARQUIVO=$(ls -1 $DIRETORIO | egrep "^AF" | egrep ".rar$") # arquivos
ls -1 $DIRETORIO | egrep "^AF" | egrep ".rar$" > /$DIRETORIO/arq.txt

if [[ -s $DIRETORIO/arq.txt ]]; then
     while IFS='' read -r line; do
     unrar x $DIRETORIO$line $DIRETORIO ; done < /$DIRETORIO/arq.txt

#  mudar para variável a verificação de conteúdo do if(se tem conteúdo)
if [[ -s variável ]]; then 

# while IFS='' read -r line; do
      unrar x $DIRETORIO$line $DIRETORIO ; done < variavel
```

Eu já tentei mudar para variavel seguindo alguns tutoriais mas foi sem sucesso.

Comment: Como você tentnou editar a variável?

Comment: Tentei assim: VAR1=ARQUIVO=$(ls -1 $DIRETORIO | egrep "^AF" | egrep ".rar$")  e tentei usar : if [[ -s $VAR1 ]]; then

Comment: @KleudySilva O `-s` que você está utilizando no `if`, serve para verificar se um arquivo existe, ou seja, não vai funcionar com uma variável pois o código irá pegar o conteúdo dessa variável e verificar se é um arquivo.

Comment: @ValdeirPsr o -s verifica se tem conteúdo dentro do arquivo, pensei que poderia usar o mesmo conceito com a variável

Comment: A intenção de usar variável era não deixar arquivos nos servidores, porem decidi que isso não é um grande problema, pois apenas eu precisaria remover os arquivos de controle no final do script. assim os arquivos serão criados no inicio do script e no termino da execução serão removidos. Obrigado para quem tentou ajudar.